# import platform specific componet to a module in nativescript angular

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have a component that I split into platform specific files
ex.component.ios.ts and ex.component.android.ts
my question is how to import it into the module because using just ex.component gives me an error
thanks.

Comment: it should be only component. like `import LoginComponent from "login.component"`. did you try this?

Comment: yes i did as i said above i used ex.component

Comment: add the error info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it can be resolved using a ex.d.ts file that has

```
export const ex: any;
```

Comment: If you have a file naming convention that would not allow this answer _(i.e. my-file.component)_, you can instead add the comment `//@ts-ignore` immediately before your _import_ statement.